# passing anonymous object to view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to pass two values from controller action to asp.net MVC 3 Razor view. I am doing like this in action method:

```
var model = new { reportid = rid, refno = refernumber};
return View(model );
```

but when i try to access it in view like this:

```
@Model.reportid
```

I get, object doesn't contain property reportid

How can I pass multiple values without using viewbag ?

Comment: Use the viewbag or create a ViewModel

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well, i strongly recommend you to use ViewModel class. But if for some reason you have phobia of extra viewmodel classes, you can use C# feature called **Tuple**

```
var model = Tuple.Create(firstObject, secondObject)
```

and then your view will be of type Tuple, for example

```
@model Tuple<int, string>
```

and you can access them like this

```
@Model.Item1
```

And then you can congratulate yourself, you have achieved nice mess with hidden meaning :)

Comment: I love how something so ugly can be so beautiful :)

Answer (score 2):

Another way to accomplish this task - is to use `ExpandoObject`.

```
dynamic model = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
model.reportid = 123
model.refno = 456;
```

Set the view model type to `dynamic`:

```
@model dynamic

@Model.reportid
@Model.refno
```